# Facebook Canvas App Height

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Facebook Canvas app and set the Height and Width to fluid.  However instead of Facebook displaying a 100% x 100% iframe all I get is a 100% wide and 800px high frame.  The rest of the page content height wise is being cut off by Facebook.  Here is my code below, can anybody figure out why I am not getting an iframe with a height of 100% when I set the Facebook website app settings height property to fluid?

I have even tried putting a height:100% for the html and div tags but still no success.  I have concluded it must be something to do with Facebook again, and how they approach to their Canvas application design.

What have Facebook messed around with this time ...

On a side note does anybody have any Canvas HTML code with CSS in which they were able to get their Facebook App centered, no-scrollbars, fluid height ....

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
  <title>My New App</title>
  <style>
        html {
           width: 750px;
           height: 100%;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 750px;
            height:100%;
            border:1px solid #000;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align:left;
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '<%= config.appID %>',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
            channelUrl: document.location.protocol + '//<%- config.siteUrl %>channel.html', // Channel File
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

        // Listen to the xfbml.render and set canvas size according to ajax rendered updates
        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(response) {
            FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
        });
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
      }(document));
    </script>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <h1>My New App</h1>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
      <p>Helo world!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

In App on Facebook Settings there are these two properties:

Canvas Url and Secure Canvas Url.

Unfortunately I put this into Canvas Url: https://www.myweb.net/
instead of: http://www.myweb.net/

When I switched from Browsing to Secure Browsing a Javascript error would occur because it was trying to load a Facebook resource over a secure https connection.  In other words the FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() could not run because of that error, and hence why my Canvas page appeared to cut off content when in fact it just was not running at all.

cheers